# Transfer URL parameters to textbox in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, parsing

Suppose I have url `www.abc.com/orders.aspx?order_id=4321` . So in this page there is one `textbox` on which page loads it should get values from url where id = 4321.

So I tried this code but it's not working. Please help

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Request.QueryString.HasKeys Then
            Dim user As String = Request.QueryString(0).ToString
            trackInput.Text = user
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Try searching. `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString)("id")`.

Comment: Put a break point somewhere and in VS's immediate window, try examining the QueryString like: "?Request.QueryString". It will provide some useful insight.

Answer (score 0):

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Request.QueryString.HasKeys Then
         Dim user As String = Request.QueryString(order_id).ToString()
         trackInput.Text = user
    End If
End Sub
```

try this..

Change ToString to ToString()

Comment: In vb.net, you don't need () at the end of ToString. Also, the QueryString is a dictionary. So the correct syntax is Request.QueryString("order_id") in this example. You're missing the double-quotes.